# How to add Package Custom Metadata Records?

Tags: custom, trailhead, casemilestone

I am working on the link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_intermediate/modules/custom_metadata_types/units/custom_metadata_types_packaging and I don't understand how to perform below steps ?

Next, add your custom metadata type to the package.

1. Click Add.
2. For the component type, select `Custom Metadata Type`.
3. Select `Threat Tier.`
4. Click Add to Package.

As per 3rd step, I simply click on the `Threat Tier` and you can see the below screen. Now how can I **Add to Package** ?? Some steps are mentioned without proper steps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You went to the wrong screen, presumably because you clicked on the **name** of the metadata type. From the Package, click **Add**, select "Custom Metadata Type" from the drop down, and **check the box** next to "Threat Tier", and finally click "Add to Package".

[image: Checking Threat Tier checkbox]